# Rails - Show Action & View for models with one-to-one association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I have a simple app with a User model & an Instructor_Profile model.  The associations between these two models is one-to-one.  I cannot get my view show.html.erb to render.  I am simply trying to display a single attribute from the Instructor_Profile model and I get this error:

NoMethodError in Instructor_profiles#show
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Models:

class User
has_one :instructor_profile

class InstructorProfile
belongs_to :user


UsersController:

def new
  @user = User.new
end


def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
    render 'static_pages/congratulations'
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end



InstructorProfilesController:

def new
  @instructor_profile = current_user.build_instructor_profile
end


def create
  @instructor_profile = current_user.build_instructor_profile(params[:instructor_profile])
  if @instructor_profile.save
    flash[:success] = "Profile created!"
    redirect_to root_path
  else
  ....
  end
end


def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @instructor_profile = @user.instructor_profile
end



Views/instructor_profiles/show.html.erb:

<p>Display Name: <%= @user.instructor_profile.name %></p>
```

Comment: Have you tried with @instructor_profile.name ?

Comment: Hi Soni.  Yes, I have tried that as well.  Same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because `@user.instructor_profile` is `nil`.
That means there is no instructor_profile corresponding to the `@user`.
Please check the `create` method inside the `UserController` to confirm whether `instructor_profile` is creating or not. Code should be something like this,

```
@user.instructor_profile = InstructorProfile.new(name: "my_name")
@user.instructor_profile.save
```

edited:

has_one association doesn't mean that every user has to have an instructor_profile. So before you call the `@user.instructor_profile.name`, just confirm that `@user` have `instructor_profile` or not. In your view, you can easily solve this error by adding one condition..

`<p>Display Name: <%= @user.instructor_profile ?  @user.instructor_profile.name : "no instructor_profile present" %></p>`.

One more thing, in `instructor_profiles_controller/show`, change the code into

```
@instructor_profile = InstructorProfile.find(params[:id])
 @user = @instructor_profile.user
```

Comment: Hi Thaha.  I think you are right about the problem.  However, I am not sure why I would have to define anything regarding instructor_profile in the UsersController.  Maybe I do not completely understand the has_one association.  But I thought that just because User has_one instructor_profile, it doesn't mean that EVERY user has to have an instructor_profile.  Is this not accurate?

Comment: Additionally, I just added my new & create actions for both of these controllers for you to see.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Thaha!  That adjustment to the show action in InstructorProfilesController fixed the problem.  I will also add the condition in my view as well.  Really appreciate your help!